# Matching regex at specific positions

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match strings using a single regex expression where I could define  constraints on their position within the text?

For example given a hex encoded file I would like to match hex representations that correspond to characters whose hex representation is larger than 0x40. The position constraint should be that matching should start at even positions.
E.g. `034673911921` should match at `46`,`73`,`91` but not at `92`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
^(?:..)*([4-9A-Fa-f][\da-fA-F])
```

which will make sure that an even number of characters precedes your capturing group.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It selects the whole string (tested with regexpal.com). Can you explain this syntax: `(?:..)`?

Comment: It's a non-capturing group matching two arbitrary characters. And yes, the match will extend from the start of the string to the end of the hex group that's larger than 0x40 (with my newest change). You'll have to use the capturing group to select the digits you wanted.

Comment: I've updated the question. Is it possible to do it in a single regex expression? With your approach I assume I need to use a programming language to access the matching group.

Comment: Well, yes, it's possible, but not for the vast majority of regex engines. You can use `(<=^(..)*)[4-9A-Fa-f][\da-fA-F]` but that requires an engine that allows arbitrary-length backreferences. .NET does allow that, most others don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the position inside a regex. For your example of only starting at even positions, that could be something like

```
/^(?:..)*([4-9a-fA-F].)/
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in two easy to understand steps: first split it into fields and then check the size. Here is an example with `sed`, I hope it will be of help:

```
echo 034673911921 | sed -nr 's7([0-9][0-9])/\1 /gp' | sed -n 's/[0-3][0-9]//gp'
```